# Getting non overlapping bbox in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, extents, overlapping-features

I have tree bbox as follow: `bbox 1`, `bbox 2`, and `bbox 3`. Now I want to get `Final bbox` from `bbox 1` in OpenLayers 5. How?

[image]

Comment: What is the role of `bbox 2` here?

Comment: Subtract `bbox 2` and `bbox 3` from `bbox 1`

Comment: But in your picture `bbox 2` (blue) is not subtracted from `Final bbox` (green), only `bbox 3` (blue) is.

Comment: @TomazicM  I presume the requirement is the bbox of the shaded area? https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PuC2.png

Comment: @Mike That's on the author of the question to confirm. What's confusing is green border that seems to be part of final result.

Comment: It's the bbox of the result of removing the overlaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in method in OpenLayers, you would need to include a third party library such as turf.js

```
var poly1 = turf.bboxPolygon(bbox1);
var poly2 = turf.bboxPolygon(bbox2);
var poly3 = turf.bboxPolygon(bbox3);
var bbox = turf.bbox(turf.difference(turf.difference(poly1, poly3), poly2));
```